# Storing individual data from a loop for further use (after the loop ends)

Tags: c#, for-loop, store

So basically I want to:

1. Store the user's input (Number)
2. Loop Number-times
3. Store another user's input (Value) within that loop
4. Sum up all the Values and assign it to Total
5. Close the loop
6. Put the if (Total > 20) statement
7. Within if condition, use each individual Value from the "for loop" block for some further calculations.

Unfortunately I get stuck because I don't know how to store each individual value after the loop is closed. How can I do that?

For clarification, this is my pseudocode:

```
int Number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] Value = new int[Number];
int Total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
{
                Console.Write("Enter {0} value", i + 1);
                Value[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Total = Total + Value[i];
}
if (Total > 20)
{
  //HERE I wan't to use each Value (every Value[i]) specified in previous for loop
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the values?

Comment: Loop over `Value[]` again `Number` times?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be no more complicated than a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (int v in Value)
{
     // where v is each of your integer values //
}
```

Comment: or a `for` loop since he knows how to use it!

Comment: That's why I didn't suggest this, (s)he is clearly new and should understand what they are currently using before being introduced to other examples like this.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I somehow thought that with another loop, the user would have to enter inputs again. Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A better perspective at your code

```
        int total = 0;
        int[] values = null;

        int number;
        if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
        {
            List<int> aux = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} value", i);
                int value;
                if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
                {
                    aux.Add(value);
                    total += value;
                }                    
            }
            values = aux.ToArray();
        }

        if(values != null)
        {
            if (total > 20)
            {
                foreach (int value in values)
                {
                    // code processing
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already stored the individual values in the array `Value[]`. You might need to clarify your question a bit to explain how you want to use the values. We're not telepathic and we can't guess what you want to do. The answer depends on that, so we can't answer your question without the extra information.

You can see how to access elements of the array by looking at the for loop you've already created.